# Xposed: How to hook Constructors with parameters in Nested Class

Tags: android, hook, xposed, xposed-framework

In order to analyse app, I need to hook

```
public final class LoadedApk {
   ……
      static final class ReceiverDispatcher {

            ReceiverDispatcher(BroadcastReceiver receiver, Context context,
            Handler activityThread, Instrumentation instrumentation,
            boolean registered) {
                  ……
            }

            final class Args extends BroadcastReceiver.PendingResult implements Runnable {

                public Args(Intent intent, int resultCode, String resultData, Bundle resultExtras,
                      boolean ordered, boolean sticky, int sendingUser) {
                     ……
                }
            }
      }
 }
```

I want to hook 2 Constructors -- **ReceiverDispatcher**、**Args**, and get the value of their parameters.

when I using findAndHookConstructor,

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher()#exact
```

Comment: I have already solved this problem using ***XPosedBridge.hookAllConstructors***